# document.getElementById not working depending on when I place the div I'm accessing

Tags: html, button, click, hide, getelementbyid

I'm trying to hide a div element on button click.
I have the following HTML code (maybe I'm reporting too much code, I'm not sure if that can be helpful, please consider the three comments I've added to the code).

```
<!-- HOME DIV -->
<div class="home" style="height: 100vh;">
<div class="home_slider_container" style="height: 100vh">
    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme home_slider">
        <div class="owl-item home_slider_item">
            <div class="home_slider_background" style="background-image:url( {% static 'images/home_slider_1.jpg' %})"></div>
            <div class="home_slider_content_container">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <div style="text-align: center; bottom: 60px;">
                                <div class="home_slider_title">CASTELLO</div>
                                <div class="home_slider_subtitle">Acquista nella tua città.</div>
                                <div class="newsletter_form_container" style="margin-top: 130px;">
                                    <form action="#" id="newsletter_form" class="newsletter_form">
<!-- BELOW IS THE DIV TO BE HIDDEN -->  
                                        <div id="myDIV" style="display: block;">CIAO</div>

<!-- BELOW IS THE BUTTON TO HIDE THE DIV -->
                                        <div class="button button_light home_button" style="display: inline-block;" onclick="show()"><a>Trova</a></div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have the following javascript function:

```
function show() {
var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
console.log(x.style.display)
x.style.display = "none";
console.log(x.style.display)
```

}

When I press the button I can see on the console the display property changing from "block" to "none", as it should, but nothing happens on the web page, the "myDiv" div does not disappear. Only if I put the "myDiv" div outside the "home" div, it does work properly!
Why does the DOM update with the correct "display" property only when I place the "myDiv" div in some place in the page?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Post your CSS as well. We need a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it works fine when I place the JavaScript part below the body end tag (). I pressed Trova and the myDiv disappeared as expected.

```js
function show() {
var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
console.log(x.style.display)
x.style.display = "none";
console.log(x.style.display)}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
body {
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="home" style="height: 100vh;">
<div class="home_slider_container" style="height: 100vh">
    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme home_slider">
        <div class="owl-item home_slider_item">
            <div class="home_slider_background"></div>
            <div class="home_slider_content_container">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <div style="text-align: center; bottom: 60px;">
                                <div class="home_slider_title">CASTELLO</div>
                                <div class="home_slider_subtitle">Acquista nella tua città.</div>
                                <div class="newsletter_form_container" style="margin-top: 130px;">
                                    <form action="#" id="newsletter_form" class="newsletter_form">
<!-- BELOW IS THE DIV TO BE HIDDEN -->  
                                        <div id="myDIV" style="display: block;">CIAO</div>

<!-- BELOW IS THE BUTTON TO HIDE THE DIV -->
                                        <div class="button button_light home_button" style="display: inline-block;" onclick="show()"><a>Trova</a></div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The OP most likely has CSS which is causing the problem. And "it works" is never an answer.